# what is the signal for qtreeview changed

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qstandarditemmodel

There is a dictionary taken from JSON file, that is represented by `QTreeView` `QStandardItemModel`.

A user can reorganize `QTreeView`(add, delete, drag-n-drop) and rename items.

The goal is: call function that reads changed `QTreeView`, makes the dictionary and writes it to initial JSON file.

I can do it by pressing a `QPushButton` after changes occurred or by binding that function to every change e.g. call function when an item is deleted, call function when an item is added, call a function when an item is renamed and so on.

Is there any way to call a function if any of changes occur? Is there such a signal that corresponds to all of the mentioned changes?

Comment: `QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()` and/or `QAbstractItemModel::layoutChanged()` signals might help.

Comment: A `QTreeView` is a view, so it's a widget. Widgets normally don't signal their updates, instead they are delivered an event when they should update. Did you mean that you wish to know when the *model* has changed? If so, you should read the documentation: see [introduction to model view programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html).

Answer (score 1):

The `rowsMoved` and `itemChanged` signals do what you think they do. See http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html

Comment: I'm looking for the way avoiding bindings function to each one change. Is there any signal for all of changes.

Comment: @SergiiArtele How do you know that there are "all" changes - i.e. why do you presume that there is more than one change? Alternatively, if you think that "binding" a function to each **kind** of change is to be avoided: well, it can't be, since there is no signal that just says "hey, something changed". There are different kinds of changes: *structural* and *non-structural*, and it differs quite a bit how you might handle them. Perhaps tell us what you need to do with such changes first.

Comment: Ok, I meant to use such a signal that covers any of changes I do. Like `selectionChanged` may be used to cover wheither item was clicked or selected by arrows on the keyboard or `keyboardSearch`.

Answer (score 1):

As @vahancho suggests in the comments, you should connect to the [layoutChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#layoutChanged) signal. All models should emit this immedaitely after making *any* changes which could affect the view. So this will include sorting and filtering, as well as re-ordering, editing, deleting, etc.

The [dataChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal is similar, but only really useful if you want to monitor specific items.

Comment: layoutChanged works in my case only for drag'n'drop. It doesn't work when I add, delete or rename item.So I will use `itemChanged` when renaming occures and I will call function that reads tree and saves its content to JSON file when delete or add

Comment: @SergiiArtele. Sorry - it seems I've never fully tested what these signals do, and so I was mislead by the Qt docs.

Comment: I have tried both dataChanged and layoutChanged and been frustrated that when performing a drag-drop operation, the signal is emitted seemingly when the drag op is in effect and not at conclusion of the drop.   I.e. the model is not fully updated!  I can not find a good signal for the conclusion of a drag-drop operation.